# Port forwarding from host machine to virtual machine through SSH

Tags: ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

I have installed apache2 web server on a virtual machine (lab 2) which has the ip address of 192.168.1.233. Now I want to access the server from my host machine's web browser. My host machine ip is 192.168.1.231. For this, I tried to use local port forwarding by using SSH. I used the following command in my host machine:

```
sudo ssh -L 1010:localhost:80 user@lab 2_ip address
```

That is, i want to listen on port 1010 on my host machine and want to forward to the virtual machine which is listening on port 80. But I couldn't access the web page running by apache2. What could be wrong here? I do not have any firewall running and I also checked that ssh is running on both machine.

Comment: does apache2 listen on the `localhost` interface?

Comment: Yes, it is listening on localhost.